# Regex tweak to remove duplicate text

Tags: regex

The regex `(?s)(.{10,})(?=\1)` is used to remove duplicates of text portions longer than 10 chars. It generally works well, but in the snippet linked to below it misses the duplication of the phrase beginning with the words "Assisted in documenting application".

Any idea how to improve the regex so it will catch that duplication?

Here's the snippet: https://regex101.com/r/sjACIb/1

Answer (score 0):

The phrase isn't immediately repeating, Another sentence separates it from its recurrence: `-Responsible for researching and writing new content for Nexus' website.`
You can add a non-capturing group to handle possible characters between the two occurences:

```
(.{10,})(?:.*)(?=\1)
```

Note that this will also match `certification` in `...LEED-CI certification (anticipating Gold Level certification).`

Edit: if you want to stick to the single line modifier, you'll have to specify that you don't want to match new lines in the repeating phrase in order to avoid catastrophic backtracking (new lines are then still allowed between a phrase and its reocurrence):

```
(?s)([^\n]{10,})(?:.*)(?=\1)
```

Comment: Hi @Tranbi, thanks for weighing in. I tried the second regex at the snippet linked to below and it causes catastrophic backtracking. Do you see any way to avoid it? Thanks again. https://regex101.com/r/Rglt6U/1

Comment: That's because regex101 doesn't handle (the string is too long) it. If you try in Python (I suppose it's your language of choice since your first link points to it) it will work. Note that your last example doesn't contain any line break so the modifier (in python `re.DOTALL` ) becomes irrelevant.